# Call to undefined method links()

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, pagination

I'm trying to display featured game in my home page but i'm getting the error :

`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::links()` when i'm changing in the HomeController :

From

```
$home = Product::inRandomOrder()->paginate($pagination);
```

To

```
$home = Product::where('featured', 'true');
```

HomeController

```
 public function public(){

        $pagination = 9;
        $categories = Category::all();

        if (request()->category) {
            $home = Product::where('category_id', request()->category)->paginate($pagination);

            $categoryName = optional($categories->where('id', request()->category)->first())->name;
        } 
        else {

        $home = Product::where('featured', 'true');
        $categoryName = 'Featured';

        }
        return view('home.index')->with([
            'home' => $home,
            'categories' => $categories,
            'categoryName' => $categoryName,
            'mode' => 'public'
        ]);  
    }
```

2020_04_09_073846_create_products_table

```
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->string('releaseDate');
            $table->boolean('featured')->default(false);
            $table->float('price');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

`{{ $homes->links() }}` in the home.blade.php (at the end of the html of course)

So every game is at 0, so it should be display a page empty whithout any game.

The pagination works fine without changing the line in the HomeController but when i'm changing to `$home = Product::where('featured', 'true');`. It's not working.

***What I tried :***

Put 5, 10 or 20 games at 1 in the featured column but same error.

Put `$home = Product::where('featured', 'true')->paginate($pagination);` but it shows me every game that i have...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what is links? is it a relation to Product? and could you show the inRandomOrder function?

Comment: When you call a function paginate in the controller, put Link in the html allows the pagination to works correctly

Comment: well then the line shouldn't work right? it has to be paginated. You say you get the wrong results if you try to paginate that line?

Comment: Yes, i'm getting no games when the column featured is at 1 and all the games when the column featured is at 0. I want to reverse that and have the games that are at 1 to display as featured.

Comment: could you try `where('featured', true)` instead of 'true'?

Comment: Oh.....it worked, it would be nice if i didn't do mistake like that, i waste so much time...Anyway, all good, thanks a lot !

Comment: which mistake was it? was it changing 'true' to true that solved it? If so, you accepted the wrong answer, ill post an answer could you accept it?

Comment: Yes it was changing 'true' to true. How can i accept the answer when you talk about that. The only answer that i can accept it's your first one that you make, don't know why. I edited it with the right answer that you said "could you try where('featured', true) instead of 'true'?" but if you want me to do otherwize tell me.

Comment: I posted my answer now. the one you accepted is not mine. Please accept the correct one. Thank you

Comment: I changed and accepted yours , thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Product::where('featured',true)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the home variable sent to the view is $home and not $homes

```
{{ $home->links() }}
```

instead of

```
{{ $homes->links() }}
```

Comment: My pagination works fine. Like I said is just the line ```$home = Product::where('featured', 'true')``` that is not working at all

Comment: ok make it **$home = Product::where('featured',true)->paginate($pagination)**